# PYTHON: import module with local folder file call = ERROR

Tags: python, import, module, path, resources

Good morning,

Structure like this:

```
-root folder
---folder_A
-----conf_file.cnf
-----module.py
---folder_B
-----script.py
```

**module.py:**

```
class ModuleFoo:
  FILE_CONST = "conf_file.cnf"
  ...
```

Execute this file, all OK. Loads data from conf file, and everything runs smooth.

**script.py:**

```
...
from folder_A.ModuleFoo import *
...

class MyScript:
  ...
  def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    self.ObjModuleFoo = ModuleFoo(...)
  ...
```

And suddenly an error:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'conf_file.cnf'
```

I know it's releated with paths, but I don't know how to exactly mount this to have the ability to import ModuleFoo on every script I want, not having to move the config file on every local project that imports it.

Can you help me please?
I've tried absolutepath, cwd, sys, etc... But don't know how to solve it, has when a module is imported, CWD changes, event real absolute path too, to the one where currently **script.py** is running.

Thanks and regards.

Comment: And you've tried defining **`FILE_CONST`** as an absolute path (i.e. starts with **`/`**)?

Comment: Thanks. Doesn't work. I don't want to specify full path on module.py. I want to import it anywhere, but module.py file open, do not change path to local execution one.

Comment: You could, in your setup file, add the root folder to the path. Then you could simply reference all the files from the project root. See here for more details on how to set up project structure.

https://python-packaging.readthedocs.io/en/latest/minimal.html

From there you can investigate how \_\_init\_\_ files work to turn folders into modules.

Answer (score 0):

OK. I've solved it like this:

On **module.py**:

```
...
import os
...
class ModuleFoo:
  FILE_CONST = f"{os.path.dirname(__file__)}/conf_file.cnf"
```

And this is it. It makes the trick.
Do you find any problem on this soultion? I know many says it's not a good idea to refeer "**file**" on things like this...